# Keras create your own generator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am building my own generator to use with fit_generator() and predict_generator() functions from keras library. My generator works but I wondering if it has been build correctly. Especially for validation and test sets.

For these two sets, I disable the data augmentation processing since it is only used for the training phase but I am still using randomness to select data from my inputs. Thus I would like to know if is it correct to still using randomness selection of data for validation set?

I think It is but I am not totally sure.

```
    def generator(inputs, labels, validation=False):  
       batch_inputs = np.zeros((batch_size, *input_shape))
       batch_labels = np.zeros((batch_size, num_classes))
       indexes = list(range(0,len(inputs))

       while True:
           for i in range(self.batch_size):
               # choose random index in inputs
               if validation:
                  index = indexes.pop()
               else:
                  index = random.randint(0, len(inputs) - 1)

               batch_inputs[i] = rgb_processing(inputs[index], validation) # data_augmentation processing functions validation=true --> disable data augmentation
               batch_labels[i] = to_categorical(labels[index], num_classes=self.num_classes)
           yield batch_inputs, batch_labels


    train_batches = generator(train.X.values, train.y.values)
    validate_batches = generator(validate.X.values, validate.y.values, validation=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the validation, the order of the image should not affect your results. So in theory, there is no problem to give the validation images in a random order. You just want to be sure that all your validation images are used only once so your results are comparable.

Comment: The problem is that it's not "random order", it's simply random. The data will not be always the same.

Comment: Ok so my mystake is that I achieve simply a random in my validation set which is bad for validation set. Instead I need to have a list (shuffled or not) and simply pop indexes. My question now is to know if taking simply a random index is still valid for training set knowing that data will not be always the same due to data augmentation on randomness on indexes taken. I edited the sample code with the @DanielMöller correction.

Comment: Yes, in the training you don't need the sames images in every epoch. That means that your loss might fluctuate but it won't bother your learning. Be careful not to use the same images in training and validation.

Comment: @DanielGL ok thanks, Yes of course I am not using same images in training and validation